# Load and run a script in Magma;

Tags: magma-ca

I am using Magma in Windows (C:\program files\magma).
I have some scripts xyz.m in the D:\scripts directory. I can't figure out how to load the scripts and run them.
Thank you for your help.
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run magma from any directory under windows. One has to create an environment variable MAGMA_PATH where the value is the directory path of the scripts.